# how to recognized my font on iOS by vsCODE?

Tags: ios, xcode

I follow all the steps to add a typo but i always have the same error :
"unrocognized font-family" for iOS.

i had my folder and i put my fonts inside :
[image]

then i had my config folder:
[image]

inside my config folder i had my export module :

```
module.exports = {
  assets: ['./assets/fonts'],
};
```

then i do the rnpm on my package.json :

```
"rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts"
    ]
  }
```

i do an npx react-native link

i check on Xcode on my info.plist and i add them :
[image]

they are also on my copy bundle :
[image]

maybe i forget something, i tryed everything and nothing is working :(

Answer (score 0):

try change font-family to 'Ambit-Regular'